# How to add comboboxitem to combobox in style(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I want to create a combobox style.In the style, I want to add 10 comboboxitems(1, 2,3,...,10) in the combobox.So how can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why exactly you would want to do this, but you can of course assign a value to the ItemsSource property in a Style:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...

<x:Array x:Key="MyComboBoxItems" Type="sys:String">
    <sys:String>1</sys:String>
    <sys:String>2</sys:String>
    <sys:String>3</sys:String>
    <sys:String>4</sys:String>
</x:Array>

<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{StaticResource MyComboBoxItems}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: IMO, it would be neater to declare a separate resource for an Array

Comment: thx a lot! I do it because I have 10 comboboxes they have same data.So i want to create a style include data.Otherwise I will have to add data to every combobox every time.

Comment: You're welcome. See the edited answer for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in `XAML` and in `C#`.

In `C#` for adding items in combox use this code in Loaded event of window:

```
comboboxname.Items.add("Item1");
comboboxname.Items.add("Item2");
comboboxname.Items.add("Item3");
```

for show default item use this :

```
comboboxname.SelectedIndex= number of Item(for example Item1 equals 0);
```